# Notification System on ELK

Tags: elasticsearch, notifications, logstash, kibana

I have an ELK stack. I need to get email notifications based on certain queries.  **How could I achieve this behavior using only open source software?**

Comment: commenting as answering is no longer possible.  
https://github.com/sirensolutions/sentinl is probably what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

elastic offers their commercial system for this, [watcher](https://www.elastic.co/products/watcher).

If you want to alert on individual events, you can use the email{} output from logstash.

Assuming that your logs are not the first thing you're monitoring, I would recommend integrating this type of check into your existing monitoring system.  You can write a script for these (like nagios, or even commercial systems) that runs the query you want.

There's more on the rational for this and some design ideas [here](http://svops.com/blog/monitoring-your-log-files/).

Comment: Watcher is great but can only be licensed as part of a bundle which is currently $9,150 (AUD) per server per year.  The minimum recommended cluster size is 3, so you're looking at $27,450 per year.

Answer (score 9):

I will sugest to have a look at elastalert :

https://github.com/Yelp/elastalert

it covers ( under apache licence ) following use cases :

"Match where there are X events in Y time" (frequency type)

- "Match when the rate of events increases or decreases" (spike type)
- "Match when there are less than X events in Y time" (flatline type)
- "Match when a certain field matches a blacklist/whitelist" (blacklist
  and whitelist type)
- "Match on any event matching a given filter" (any
  type)
- "Match when a field has two different values within some time"
  (change type)
- "Match when a never before seen term appears in a
  field" (new_term type)
- "Match when the number of unique values for a
  field is above or below a threshold (cardinality type)